# How to use redux-toolkit createSlice with React class components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've started using the redux-toolkit slicers in functional components, (example from react-redux example)

slicer:

```
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: state => {
      state.value += 1;
    },
    decrement: state => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

use in component:

```
const count = useSelector(selectCount);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

return (
  <button
    className={styles.button}
    aria-label="Increment value"
    onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}
  >
)
```

my question is how can I use this slicer in the class component since I cant use hooks inside them.
I've tried using connect (from redux) but I can't find a way to "stitch" the actions and selectors from the slicer to my component.
I couldn't find any documentation on this as well.

Comment: The connect HoC (not hook) predates the hooks, and you can find the information here - https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Class vs. function components and redux-toolkit vs "vanilla" redux are two independent decisions that don't have any impact on each other.  (Though you should be aware that function components and hooks are recommended over class components for everything React).

> I've tried using connect (from redux) but I can't find a way to "stitch" the actions and selectors from the slicer to my component.

How do the docs "stitch" the actions and selectors when using `useDispatch` and `useSelector`?  Do that, but with the `connect` higher-order component instead.

The `increment()` function in the docs example that you posted doesn't just magically exist, it needs to be imported from the slice.  You can export the entire `actions` object and use `actions.increment` but you usually see the actions exported as individual variables.

From [the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/basic-tutorial#introducing-createreducer):

> Most of the time, you'll probably want to use ES6 destructuring syntax to pull out the action creator functions as variables, and possibly the reducer as well:

Your slice file might look like this:

```
const counterSlice = createSlice( /* same as before */ );

// destructure actions and reducer from the slice (or you can access as counterSlice.actions)
const { actions, reducer } = counterSlice;

// export individual action creator functions
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = actions;

// often the reducer is a default export, but that doesn't matter
export default reducer;
```

The first argument of `connect` is [`mapStateToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops--object), where you use selectors (either inline arrow functions `state => state.something` or selector functions that you import) to create an object of props from the state.  That might look like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  count: state.counter.value
});
```

The second argument [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object--dispatch-ownprops--object) is optional.  If you pass an object with your action creators, your component will receive versions of those action creators that are already bound to `dispatch`.  You would be able to call `this.props.increment()` directly rather than `this.props.dispatch(increment())`.  You will see this syntax commonly used in tutorials with `connect`.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { increment, decrement } from "./counterSlice";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Count is {this.props.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.increment()}>
          Increment
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.decrement()}>
          Decrement
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  count: state.counter.value
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { increment, decrement };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

If you leave off the `mapDispatchToProps` argument entirely, your component receives the raw `dispatch` function.  You would call the dispatch on you imported action creators like `this.props.dispatch(increment())`.  This syntax is more similar to how `useDispatch` is used.  Both `connect` and `useDispatch` give you access to the `dispatch` function and you can call that function with an action that you create from an action creator function like `increment()` or `decrement()`.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { increment, decrement } from "./counterSlice";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Count is {this.props.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(increment())}>
          Increment
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(decrement())}>
          Decrement
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  count: state.counter.value
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

[Complete CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-class-components-hit15?file=/src/ClassComponentV2.tsx)

Comment: Do you know how people would accomplish the "interface MyComponentProps {
  dispatch: Dispatch;
  count: number;
}" part in your code example if not using typescript? I'm not using type script, and am trying to figure out how to get the component to know about the props.

Comment: @Maiya you could use `prop-types`: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: this was very well explained. Thank you!