# Redux Toolkit and Class Components - React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to using React Native, and was recently planning on using Redux Toolkit with my project. I was previously using standard Redux, but really like how RTK keeps everything concise with slices.

My project currently uses Class Components for the Screens and would like to keep it that way, but I can't find any documentation on using RTK with Class Components, only with Functional Components. I wanted to know if it was possible to use Class Components and what changes need to be made in order to add RTK. I feel like I should be able to just import the actions from the Slices and then use MapDispatchToProps, but any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use redux-toolkit createSlice with React class components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66277647/how-to-use-redux-toolkit-createslice-with-react-class-components)

Answer (score 1):

Redux Toolkit is purely about writing Redux logic, and is totally separate from how you write your React components and use React-Redux.

So, you can use any combination of:

- Redux logic: vanilla hand-written Redux or RTK
- React-Redux: `connect` + class components, or function components + hooks

See the React-Redux docs on using `connect`:

- https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate
- https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch