# action not changing state in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to implement react-redux in my react 17.0.2 project

My login slice code:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  loggedIn: false,
  userEmail: '',
  token: ''
}

export const loginSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'login',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      login: (state, action) => {
        state.loggedIn = true;
        state.token = action.payload.token;
        state.userEmail = action.payload.email;
        localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
        localStorage.setItem('email', action.payload.email);
      },
      logout: (state) => {
        state.loggedIn = false;
        state.token = '';
        state.userEmail = '';
        localStorage.setItem('token', '');
        localStorage.setItem('email', '');
      },
    },
  })
  
  // Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
  export const { login, logout } = loginSlice.actions
  
  export default loginSlice.reducer
```

dispatching login action as following:

```
.then((data) => {
            that.state.loggedIn = true;
            // that.globalState.setPropertyValue('token', data.token);
            store.dispatch({
                              type: 'login',
                              payload:{
                                loggedIn: that.state.loggedIn,
                                email: that.state.email,
                                token: data.token
                              }
                            });
            this.props.navigate('/admin/manage-indicator')
        })
```

This action is correctly sent but state change is not being executed. I am new to redux so not able to find the error here.

Comment: You shouldn't be making side effects in your reducers.

Comment: @possum what is a side effect? I am sorry, I am new to react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: I tried to dispatch actions directly through store.dispatch which is not working in react-redux

I had 2 type of components: class and functional

In my solution:
For class components, I used 'connect' like following

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { login, logout };

export default connect(
  null, 
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

and for functional components, one has to use useSelector and useDispatch hooks.

Ref: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66277647/how-to-use-redux-toolkit-createslice-with-react-class-components)